# Time period for Mercury

Tags: general-relativity, rotational-dynamics, orbital-motion

General Relativity predicts the orbit of Mercury to be not closed. Does time period of orbit lose it's meaning in general relativity? Does Mercury have a variable time period?

Comment: The orbit isn’t closed in Newtonian gravity either, due to the gravity of other planets.

Comment: Okay. But then how does one define period meaningfully anyway?

Answer (score 2):

> Does time period of orbit loses it's meaning in general relativity?

The period of an orbit is the time that it takes to go 360 degrees around the barycenter. It doesn’t matter if perihelion moves a bit or if the distance to the barycenter is slightly off.